# Breeze inlineCount is undefined

Tags: breeze

I'm doing a query:

```
var query = entityQuery.from('Items').where(fullPredicate).orderBy(sortingColumn + ' ' + ordering).skip(numOfEntities * (pageNum - 1)).take(numOfEntities).inlineCount();

return manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);
```

Controller looks like this:

```
[Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All,
                    AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions,
                    MaxNodeCount = 10000)]
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Item> Items()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.Items.Include("A").Include("B").Include("C");
        }
```

Response is pure JSON with all Items and linked (Included) items (A, B and C), but without inlineCount. While reading data in querySucceeded, there is a parameter called inlineCount but is set to undefined.

I've tried adding the following to web.config, but it didn't help.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="X-InlineCount" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Upgraded from 1.4.0 to 1.4.2 as well, but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the following solved the problem. There is probably a bug where inlineCount is not included in AllFunctions or something.

```
[Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All,
    AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions,
    MaxNodeCount = 10000)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally got my server to respond with correct **inlinecount** value using [Breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com) client and Breeze Web Api server control (BreezeController).

You need to add the attribute **BreezeQueryable** instead of the standard OData **Queryable**.  The *inlinecount* will not be included in the server response by the Breeze controller, unless you include this attribute above your method.

So the following server code resolved my issue:

```
[HttpGet, BreezeQueryable]
public IQueryable<FinDataModelsPublic.InvoicesView> InvoicesView(ODataQueryOptions<FinDataModelsPublic.InvoicesView> options, int custId)
{
    return FBll.InvoicesView(custId);
}
```

Above the Bll.InvoicesView is a method from my data model returning IQueryable result.
Hope this helps